# How to search exact text without matching case in Elasticsearch

Tags: spring-boot, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-query

I want to search the user name in the **Elasticsearch**. For this I want to match the exact username ignoring its case whether it is capital or small, I just want to find that user name. I'm using the following query for this:

```
QueryBuilder queryBuilder = QueryBuilders.termQuery("user_name.keyword", userName);
NativeSearchQuery build = new NativeSearchQueryBuilder().withQuery(queryBuilder).build();
List<Company> companies = elasticsearchTemplate.queryForList(build, User.class);
```

But it is also matching the exact word with the case. **for example: if the user name is "Ram" and I search "ram" then it is not returning that name. If I search "Ram" then it is giving me the result. But I want that it only matches the word not the case of that word.** Please, someone, help me to solve this problem. I searched a lot but couldn't find any solution.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Issue is you are using `user_name.keyword`  and `terms` query. `Terms` query matches exact word instead of that you can use `MatchQueryBuilder` query :

### Code :

```
QueryBuilder queryBuilder = QueryBuilders.matchQuery("user_name", userName);
NativeSearchQuery build = new NativeSearchQueryBuilder().withQuery(queryBuilder).build();
List<Company> companies = elasticsearchTemplate.queryForList(build, User.class);
```

When using `.keyword` field, elastic does not analyze the text but if you use your text field ElasticSerach analyzes your text using default analyzer on that field. Default Analyzer basically converts your text in  lowercase and remove stopwords from it. You can read about it from here : https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-standard-analyzer.html

Since you want to do case insensitive search so you don't need to use `.keyword`.

Also, `terms` query matches exact terms but again since you want to do case insensitive search you should you `match` query which also by default internally converts your search text in lowercase and then search the field for that text.

And, now since both your field and search term is in lowercase you can do case insensitive search **but this will not do exact match**.

**For doing exact case insensitive match** you need to update your index and use normalizer with your keyword field which guarantees that the analysis chain produces a single token and case insensitive search. You can read more about it from [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/normalizer.html).

### Index Creation:

```
curl -X PUT "localhost:9200/<index-name>" -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d 
{
        "settings": {
            "analysis": {
                "normalizer": {
                    "case_insensitive_normalizer": {
                        "type": "custom",
                        "filter": [
                            "lowercase"
                        ]
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        "mappings": {
            "properties": {
                "user_name": {
                    "type": "keyword",
                    "normalizer": "case_insensitive_normalizer"
                }
            }
        }
}
```

I have indexed these documents :

### Doc1 :

```
{
        "user_name": "Ram"
}
```

### Doc2 :

```
{
        "user_name": "Ram Mohan"
}
```

### Search Query :

```
{
     "query" : {
        "match" : {
            "user_name" : "ram"
        }
     }
}
```

### Result :

```
"hits": [
            {

                "_source": {
                    "user_name": "Ram"
                }
            }
]
```

Comment: it didn't work. for example, there are two users "Ram" and "Mohan Ram". if I search "ram" then it is returning both users but I want only "Ram" not "Mohan Ram".

Comment: Sorry, missed that case. Have updated my answer you need to use Normalizer during index creation time for doing case insensitive exact match search.

Comment: Sure let me know if you face any issue.

Comment: can you give me curl URL for this request

Comment: Have added curl request for index creation in my answer

Comment: can we talk in chat, when i run this curl url it is giving me error

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/214088/discussion-between-prerna-gupta-and-user979879).

Comment: problem is solved. Thank You so much for your help.

Comment: Glad to know your issue is solved . Can you please accept and upvote the answer.

Answer (score 2):

Try to use Lowercase Token Filter in your index mapping.

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-lowercase-tokenfilter.html

Such token filter is applied in both indexing and searching so "Ram" will be indexed as "ram" and then if you'll search for "rAm" it'll be changed to "ram" so it'll hit your document.

Comment: will it works in case of "Mohan Ram" then it should not return that record when I searched for "rAm"

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do case insensitive match on a keyword field, you can use [normalizer](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/normalizer.html) with a lowercase filter

> The normalizer property of keyword fields is similar to analyzer
>   except that it guarantees that the analysis chain produces a single
>   token.

```
{
  "settings": {
    "analysis": {
      "normalizer": {
        "lowercase_normalizer": {
          "type": "custom",
          "filter": [
            "lowercase"
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "name": {
        "type": "text",
        "fields": {
          "keyword": {
            "type": "keyword",
            "normalizer": "lowercase_normalizer"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Data**

```
POST index41/_doc
{
  "name":"Ram"
}
```

**Query:**

```
{
  "query": {
    "term": {
      "name.keyword": {
        "value": "ram"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Result:**

```
"hits" : [
      {
        "_index" : "index41",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "IyieGHIBZsF59xnAhb47",
        "_score" : 0.6931471,
        "_source" : {
          "name" : "Ram"
        }
      }
    ]
```

Comment: normalizer dont you think its overkill and I guess its costly as well

Comment: @es-enthu question is to do exact match on text field. If Match query is used on text field which by default has standard analyzer converting it to lower case, it will return false matches ex  If there are two documents with text  "A B" and "A" respectively. If user searches on "A" both documents will be returned as only tokens are matched. When using term query some way is needed to convert text to lower case, since analyzer  cannot be used on keyword field , option left is to use normalizer.

Comment: Both in case of  text field and keyword with normalizer , tokens are changed to lowercase so overhead is same. Let me know if I have missed anything regarding normalizer

Comment: when i'm going to apply your solution, it is giving me error

Comment: under the mapping object, you have to add type. then I will work

Comment: @user979879 It is working as it is in version 7.* . What is your elasticsearch version?

Comment: @user979879 It should have worked . Can you add full query you executed?

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use the text field on your user-name field, text field uses by [default standard analyzer](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-standard-analyzer.html) which lowercase the tokens, and then match query applies the same analyzer which is used index time(in this case, standard) which will provide you case-insensitive search.

**Tokens generated using the standard analyzer**

```
POST /_analyzer

{
    "text" : "ram",
    "analyzer" : "standard"
}

{
    "tokens": [
        {
            "token": "ram",
            "start_offset": 0,
            "end_offset": 3,
            "type": "<ALPHANUM>",
            "position": 0
        }
    ]
}
```